# nginx: hide/unhide page elements (via CSS)

Tags: nginx

I'm using to [adblock2privoxy](https://projects.zubr.me/wiki/adblock2privoxy). adblock2privoxy will generate .filter file, .action file to /etc/privoxy/ and .css files to /var/www/privoxy. I follow the guide to setup nginx to hide page elements (via CSS) but it doesn't work.

From adblock2privoxy guide

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #ab2p css domain name (optional)
        server_name privoxy.zubr.me;

        #root = webDir parameter value
        root /var/www/privoxy;

        location ~ ^/[^/.]+\..+/ab2p.css$ {
            # first reverse domain names order
                    rewrite ^/([^/]*?)\.([^/.]+)(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?/ab2p.css$ /$9/$8/$7/$6/$5/$4/$3/$2/$1/ab2p.css last;
        }

        location ~ (^.*/+)[^/]+/+ab2p.css {
            # then try to get CSS for current domain
            # if it is unavailable - get CSS for parent domain
            try_files $uri $1ab2p.css;
        }
}
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
#user html;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /var/www/privoxy;

        location ~ ^/[^/.]+\..+/ab2p.css$ {
            rewrite ^/([^/]*?)\.([^/.]+)(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?(?:\.([^/.]+))?/ab2p.css$ /$9/$8/$7/$6/$5/$4/$3/$2/$1/ab2p.css last;
        }

        location ~ (^.*/+)[^/]+/+ab2p.css {
            try_files $uri $1ab2p.css;
        }

    }

}
```

And this is systemd log file of nginx

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2014-08-29 09:08:01 ICT; 10s ago
  Process: 2806 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2807 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2807 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr
           └─2808 nginx: worker process                                  

Aug 29 09:08:01 manjaro systemd[1]: PID file /run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Aug 29 09:08:01 manjaro systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Aug 29 09:08:06 manjaro nginx[2806]: 2014/08/29 09:08:06 [error] 2808#0: *1 "/var/www/privoxy/exec/obidos/external-search/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/external-search/?field-keywords=dfhaskd&mode=blended&tag=mozilla-20&sourceid=Mozilla-search HTTP/1.1", host: "www.amazon.com"
Aug 29 09:08:06 manjaro nginx[2806]: 2014/08/29 09:08:06 [error] 2808#0: *1 open() "/var/www/privoxy/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET http://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "www.amazon.com"
Aug 29 09:08:07 manjaro nginx[2806]: 2014/08/29 09:08:07 [error] 2808#0: *1 open() "/var/www/privoxy/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET http://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "www.amazon.com"
```

I'm a newbie and I need your helps.

Comment: The errors say nginx can't find files at `/etc/nginx/html/`. Is that where your site files are installed? If not, where in your configuration are you telling nginx where to look for them?

Comment: Acording to original nginx.conf, it does not contain index.html and favicon.ico at all, it's only point to css files. The goal of configuration is to hide site elements: you access to a site through nginx proxy and it will hide your unwanted things. The guide is wrong, may be?

Comment: You are confusing me. Nginx is an http daemon. It exists to accept http requests from the internet and send responses; configuration dictates whether those responses are files it finds in the filesystem, documents generated by software, or responses it relays (proxies) from another httpd. The error messages in your log indicate it's looking for files to return at a certain path; if it can't find those files, it returns an error. It's pretty simple.